# AMPScript: Is there an easy way to have dynamic date format based on Same Month vs Different Months?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, datetime, date

I want to create a list of events that will show event start dates and end dates. I have a data extension that stores the StartDate and EndDates. Is there an easy way to make the date format dynamic to accomplish the below:

If the dates are in the same month, I want the text to display this:
March 5 - 7, 2023.

But if the dates are not in the same month, I want the text to display:
March 27 - April 2, 2023.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```ampscript
%%[

set @startDate = dateparse("2023-01-01")
set @endDate = dateparse("2023-02-07")

if datepart(@startDate, "M") == datepart(@endDate, "M") 
   and datepart(@startDate, "Y") == datepart(@endDate, "Y") then
   
   set @combinedDate = concat(formatDate(@startDate, "MMMM d"), " - ", formatDate(@endDate, "d, YYYY"))

elseif datepart(@startDate, "M") != datepart(@endDate, "M") 
   and datepart(@startDate, "Y") == datepart(@endDate, "Y") then

   set @combinedDate = concat(formatDate(@startDate, "MMMM d"), " - ", formatDate(@endDate, "MMMM d, YYYY"))    

else 

   set @combinedDate = concat(formatDate(@startDate, "MMMM d, YYYY"), " - ", formatDate(@endDate, "MMMM d, YYYY"))    

endif

]%%
%%=v(@startDate)=%%
<br>%%=v(@endDate)=%%
<br>%%=v(@combinedDate)=%%
```

Try it yourself: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/7mifr7Hi

Comment: This is indeed more elegant. I am consistently brutal in abusing _datePart_ rather than going with _formatDate_ approach

Comment: This worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I normally don't write Ampscript as and answer to questions which don't show any research, but I found this particular logic to be quite interesting.

As you see below, I have created the script based on your use case, and I have allowed myself to extend it to cover (probably quite rare) cases, where start and end dates are in different years:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @startDate = AttributeValue("startDate")
SET @endDate = AttributeValue("endDate")
SET @startMonth = datePart(@startDate, "M")
SET @endMonth = datePart(@endDate, "M")
SET @startYear = datePart(@startDate, "Y")
SET @endYear = datePart(@endDate, "Y")
IF @startMonth == @endMonth AND @startYear == @endYear THEN
SET @displayText = CONCAT(datePart(@startDate, "monthName"),' ',datePart(@startDate, "D"),' - ',datePart(@endDate, "D"), ,datePart(@endDate, "Y"))
ELSEIF @startYear == @endYear AND @startMonth != @endMonth THEN
SET @displayText = CONCAT(datePart(@startDate, "monthName"),' ',datePart(@startDate, "D"),' - ',datePart(@endDate, "monthName"), ' ',datePart(@endDate, "D"),', ',datePart(@endDate, "Y"))
ELSE 
SET @displayText = CONCAT(datePart(@startDate, "monthName"),' ',datePart(@startDate, "D"),', ',datePart(@startDate, "Y"),' - ',datePart(@endDate, "monthName"), ' ',datePart(@endDate, "D"),', ',datePart(@endDate, "Y"))
ENDIF
]%%
```